# Reactjs 18: Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I don't understand how this is.
just a simple function component but it still shows the error: Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const DetailTitle = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    console.log(params);
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="container">
                <h2>DetailTitle</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DetailTitle();
```

Comment: Typo, `export default DetailTitle();` should be `export default Detailtitle;`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Comment: thanks, but show other error Functions are not valid as a React child

Comment: Can you edit this post to include the new details or make a new post with a [mcve]?

Comment: @AnhVũ how could you fix it?

Comment: @OgünBirinci i edited export default DetailTitle() -> export default Detailtitle. follow 1st comment

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you use extension when create a function or other in react. It is very convenient. With `Reactjs code snippets`
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xabikos.ReactSnippets

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is not relevant

Comment: When you use `extension`. it is generate `example code`. After that, you write anymore in that.